# SQL design for similar tables with few column differences

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am working on an application that deals with questions and answers.  My answers can be of different types ranging from int, text, image, option, etc.. And I wonder if it is a good practice to separate those into different tables like below?

```
Question            QuestionAnswer
--------            -------------
int Id               int QuestionId
int typeId           int AnswerId

TextAnswer          ImageAnswer    OptionAnswer        IntAnswer
----------          -----------    ------------        ---------
int AnswerId        int AnswerId   int AnswerId        int AnswerId
nvarchar Value      binary Value   int Value           int Value
                                   int OptionTypeId
```

I thought about aggregating all those into one single Answer table but then it will be filled with nullable fields and I am afraid that might introduce some bugs if I am not careful.  Is that a good idea or is this design a good practice in separating different types of answers?  Or perhaps is there a better approach to this ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of one table (for all answers), four tables (for each type of answer), or five tables (one for all answers, then one specific to each type) depends on two factors.

The most important is:  How will the data be used?  The second is:  What database are you using?

Let me dispense with the second part first.  Some databases (notably Postgres) have built-in support for table inheritance.  You can read the [documentation];
[1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-inheritance.html); it probably does what you want.

For other databases how do you choose?  Well, you have a table with `AnswerId` in it.  That suggests that you want a single entity, with an automatically generated primary key.

So, do you store all the information in that table or not?  One argument of putting all the columns in a single table is simplicity:  all the data is in one place.  You can enforce `NULL`-ness of values using `check` constraints.  One downside is that adding a new type requires modifying the table.

Another alternative is to have each of specific tables.  They can use `AnswerId` as the primary key, as well as having it as a foreign key to `Answers`.  This makes it each to add new types. However, it can be cumbersome to ensure that an answer has only one type.  The joins are a bit more complicated.

Under most circumstances, I would tend to go with one table and the proliferation of columns, especially if I knew the expected range of types in advance.